# Passing calculated value to Django template

Tags: python, django

I'm pretty new to Django and I'm having trouble with passing a variable to a Django template.  My code finds the average of an Integer field from the database (using Django's AVG) then perform a calculation on the result. Ultimately I would like to pass the result of this calculation to a template.

My model.py is:

```
from django.db import models

class Post(models.Model):
    fname = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    lname= models.CharField(max_length=25)
    reading=models.IntegerField(default=100)
    entrytime=models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self
```

The view is:

```
from django.views.generic import TemplateView, ListView
from django.db.models import Avg
from .models import Post

class ShowCalcView(ListView):
    model=Post
    template_name = 'calc.html'

    def calca1c(request):

        context = Post.objects.aggregate(Avg('reading'))
        r=context['reading__avg']
        rs = (46.7 + r) / 28.7
        context['calc']  = rs
        return context
```

The template is:

```
<h1>Approximate A1C</h1>

<p>Approximate A1c:  {{ calc }}</p>
```

I have tried using {{ calc }}, {{ calc.rs}}, {{ calc['rs'] }}, and just about every other combination I can think of but the value is not being passed.  I have checked the function in the shell, and it produces the desired result.  I'm probably missing something obvious but I cannot figure it out.

Thank you for your assistance.

Answer (score 1):

The context for a view is generated from a [`get_context_data()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/class-based-views/mixins-simple/#django.views.generic.base.ContextMixin.get_context_data) method. This is what you need to override to inject additional context into the view. As it is currently your `getca1c()` method will never be used because it is not something that Django looks for.

So you would do something like this:

```
def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
    context['calc'] = self.getca1c(self)
    return context
```

You would then modify `getca1c()` to return just a number that is the average you want to display:

```
def calca1c(self):
    result = Post.objects.aggregate(Avg('reading'))
    r = result ['reading__avg']
    return (46.7 + r) / 28.7
```

(side note - the first argument to this method is `self` - i.e., the view class instance - and not a request object).

And then in your template:

```
<p>Approximate A1c:  {{ calc }}</p>
```

Comment: Thank you!  This worked with one tweak.  self.gatcalc(self) returned an error (takes 1 positional argument but 2 were presented), so I removed the (self) from this call and it now works perfectly.  Thank you so much!!!